# How to handle x-ms-dynamic-schema with an array result?

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I am creating a custom connector in Microsoft Flow/Logic Apps, based on a Swagger file with Microsoft extensions (x-ms-dynamic-schema and x-ms-dynamic-values).

I now want to GET an array of objects. Each of these objects has the same JSON schema.
Using the x-ms-dynamic-schema extension, one can state that the Logic Apps/Flow designer needs to fetch the JSON schema of the response so that you can provide the properties of your object.

What I want to achieve is:

- I have an action on my connector ("ListEntities") that gets the array of objects I'm interested in, of a certain entity (= type of object).
- The same action picks up the schema for that entity type and displays the properties of the response.

What I tried so far:

The operation to get the schema:

> ```
>     "/api/entitydefinitions/{type}": {
>         "get": {
>             "summary": "Get Entity Definition Schema",
>             "description": "Gets the schema of an entity definition.",
>             "operationId": "GetEntitySchemaByDefinition",
>             "produces": [
>                 "application/json"
>             ],
>             "parameters": [
>                 {
>                     "name": "type",
>                     "type": "string",
>                     "in": "path",
>                     "description": "Select Entity you want to query",
>                     "required": true,
>                     "x-ms-summary": "Select Entity"
>                 }
>             ],
>             "responses": {
>                 "200": {
>                     "description": "OK",
>                     "schema": {
>                         "type": "object"
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

The operation to get the list of entities:

```
        "/api/entitydefinitions/{type-dynamic}/entities": {
        "get": {
            "summary": "List entities",
            "description": "Gets entities",
            "operationId": "ListEntitiesByDefinition",
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "type-dynamic",
                    "type": "string",
                    "in": "path",
                    "description": "Select entity definition",
                    "required": true,
                    "x-ms-summary": "Entity Definition",
                    "x-ms-dynamic-values": {
                        "operationId": "ListEntityDefinitions",
                        "value-path": "name",
                        "value-title": "name",
                    }
                }
            ],
            "responses": {
                "200": {
                    "description": "OK",
                    "schema": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/ListEntitiesByDefinitionResponse"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The definition of the response for the above

> ```
>     "ListEntitiesByDefinitionResponse": {
>         "type": "object",
>         "x-ms-dynamic-schema": {
>             "operationId": "GetEntitySchemaByDefinition",
>             "parameters": {
>                 "type": {
>                     "parameter": "type-dynamic"
>                 }
>             },
>             "value-path": "items"
>         }
>     },
> ```

Now, an example of my output:

```
[
{
    "id": 4541,
    "identifier": "123456789",
    "Name": "Name 1",
    "Description": "",
},
{
    "id": 4542,
    "identifier": "987654321",
    "Name": "FromPostman",
    "Description": "",
}
]
```

And my schema:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "title": "Example",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "integer",
                "x-ms-summary": "id"
            },
            "identifier": {
                "type": "string",
                "x-ms-summary": "identifier"
            },
            "Name": {
                "type": "string",
                "x-ms-summary": "Name"
            },
            "Description": {
                "type": "string",
                "x-ms-summary": "Description"
            }
        },
        "required": []
    }
}
```

The problem is that my flow app does show me the properties in design mode:

[image]

BUT, I would've expected a loop (apply to each) to be inserted

The flow itself also doesn't work, just because it doesn't loop the objects in the array.

[image]

Spent way too much time on this already and looking for your help.

Comment: Some follow up on this: the Swagger file on the OpenAPI extensions for custom connectors in Microsoft Flow found on https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/customapi-how-to-swagger/#x-ms-dynamic-schema has the same issue.

Comment: Late 2018... dynamic array-based-schema is still not supported https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/I-Found-A-Bug/Dynamic-schema-determined-properties-of-items-in-a-collection/m-p/144602

Answer (score 0):

Well.. you can go against Azure Flow design... or you may decide to work with it.

Let's try to replace this output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 4541,
        "identifier": "123456789",
        "Name": "Name 1",
        "Description": "",
    },
    {
        "id": 4542,
        "identifier": "987654321",
        "Name": "FromPostman",
        "Description": "",
    }
]
```

With this one:

```
{
     "values":
     [
        {
            "id": 4541,
            "identifier": "123456789",
            "Name": "Name 1",
            "Description": "",
        },
        {
            "id": 4542,
            "identifier": "987654321",
            "Name": "FromPostman",
            "Description": "",
        }
    ]
}
```

I know.. it is the "same" output but with different approach. This way, you may use the `values` field in a new `apply to each` action and manipulate it from there

> BUT, I would've expected a loop (apply to each) to be inserted

As you say - if you want a chance to use that action - first suit your output format to Azure Flow requirements and carry on from there.

**In short - try to change your schema definition to:**

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties":
    {
         "values":
         {
             "type": "array"
             "items": "..."
         }
    }
}
```